# How to write to an arbitrary storage slot using assembly in Solidity smart contracts?

Tags: assembly, storage, solidity

I am trying to understand the basics of storage manipulation using Solidity assembly (Yul) by changing the storage slot for a variable and trying to read it afterwards to see if it's stored in the correct slot but I don't get the return value I expect when calling seeSlot():

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract Assembly {
    uint public age = 30;

    function changeStorageSlot(uint newSlot) pure external {
        bytes storage _age;
        assembly {
            _age.slot := newSlot
        }
    }
 
    function seeSlot() external view returns(uint) {
        uint _age = age;
        assembly {
            let sl:= sload(_age)
            sl := age.slot
            return (sl, 0x20)
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors. Let's follow the execution of `seeSlot()`:

- `uint _age = age;`

Here `age` is read from storage and saved in the variable `_age` on the stack. So `_age = 30`.

- `let sl := sload(_age)`

Here we are reading from storage at slot `_age`, so at slot 30. `sl` is a variable on the stack. `sl = 0` since at slot 30 there's nothing.

- `sl := age.slot`

The value of `sl` is overwritten with slot `age` is saved in storage, so `0`.

- `return (sl, 0x20)`

`return` returns the memory from `sl` to `sl+0x20`. Since we haven't saved anything in memory it returns `0`.

The correct function is something like this:

```js
    function seeSlot() external view returns(uint) {
        assembly {
            let sl:= sload(age.slot)   // => sl = 30
            mstore(0x00, sl)           // store in memory at 0x00
            return (0x00, 0x20)        // return first word of memory
        }
    }
```

Regarding changing the storage slot of a state variable, it can't be done and can lead to bugs in the solidity code.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain. It helped a lot. Regarding what you say about changing the storage slot of a state variable, isn't that how diamond storage works with EIP-2535 (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535#diamond-storage-1)

Comment: Diamond storage is used to save variable at a specific slot. This slot is never changed. It's only a way to keep track of the same variable in multiple contract implementations (facets) and during upgrades.